# ASP.NET execute function before Render()

Tags: asp.net, url, seo, render

Finally i found some solution about how to call function from aspx page, couze i needed to make dynamic urls.

Im searching on Google for several weeks, but i didnt found how to make dynamic routing depend of current locale like:

```
site.com/en/home - when CurrentCulture is en-EN and
site.com/fr/home - When CurrentCulture is fr-FR.
```

I found one solution where i call function from aspx, to check CurrentCulture and print a string.

```
 <%@ Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
 <%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
<script runat="server">
void Demo() {

    CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

    string ime = currentCulture.ToString();

    Response.Write(ime);
}</script>
```

and on same aspx page i have

```
<a href="<% Demo(); %>/default.aspx">CLICK</a>
```

But now i have problem with my "Move JavaScript at bottom of page, after form tag" Class. On debug mode, i noticed that

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
```

where my class is, runs before Demo() function....

ANY suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly calling `Response.Write` in your function, have it return a string and out put that where needed.

If you simply need to call the function, you can discard the result. You can the call the function from the overridden `Render` function:

Functions:

```
public string Demo() {

    CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

    string ime = currentCulture.ToString();

    return ime;
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
  Demo();
  // rest of code
}
```

Markup:

```
// .NET 4.0
<a href="<%: Demo() %>/default.aspx">CLICK</a>

// .NET < 4.0
<a href="<%= Demo() %>/default.aspx">CLICK</a>
```

Comment: It show me some error on <a href="<%: Demo(); %>/default.aspx">CLICK</a> line, Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected. p.s this is webforms, not mvc

Comment: @NovkovskiStevoBato - What version of .NET are you using? Is `Demo` returning a string?

Comment: 4.0 and yes, Demo() return string. My Demo() its same as you  wrote here

Comment: @NovkovskiStevoBato - I see my mistake now. Remove the `;` after `Demo()`.

Comment: Yep now is working but only on HTML tags like <a href=""> not on asp.net controls like  <asp:HyperLink  NavigateUrl="<%: Demo() %>/default.aspx". When i execute, HyperLink link is same <%: Demo() %>/default.aspx

Comment: @NovkovskiStevoBato - You _can't_ use `<%:%>` within a server side control. You need to set it in your code behind.